# Websphere Commerce-TypedProperty

Tags: java, jsp, websphere, websphere-7, websphere-commerce

Can anyone help me to understand the usage of TypedProperty in websphere commerce?
ie,How to pass values from one jsp to other using TypedProperty without a command class.I would prefer to  handle it in my client side itself without invoking Command class..can anyone help me to sort out it?

Answer (score 1):

Typed property is usually used to pass values from controller commands to JSPs. If you just want to pass values from one JSP to another, create a form in your first JSP and submit it to the second.

Comment: Can  we use TypedProperty for getting values from 1 class to other?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a form submit, set the values you need to pass in  element. In the results jsp you can get those values using ${WCParam.xxx} .

FYI - To list out all the values in WCParam object try to print the below in JSP :
${WCParamValues}

We use typedProperty when we need to send anything from the command. For example, you give an order ID from the first JSP and want to get the final amount to be passed the result JSP. Here in the command we use the orderID from the request object -> Then we use the OrderAccessBean to get the OrderTotal -> then we set this to a TypedProperty object -> we then set this TypedProperty object to request properties using setRequestProperties() OOB method in a controller command.

Hope this makes it clear !

Answer (score 0):

TypedProperty is a class in Java which can be compared to Hashmap in Java for better understanding. It is a name value pair combination.

I just wanted to understand the problem before answering further.

1. Why do you want to use TypedProperty in Jsp to pass the value from one jsp to another?
2. Are you importing the second jsp or including the second jsp to which you have to pass the values to?

If you are importing, you can use c:param tag to pass the values to the second jsp.

For included jsps, the values are already available in the second JSP.

Please include code snippets to explain your problem so that it can be answered clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters from one jsp to another by using the following code snippet:

```
<c:import url="child.jsp">
 <c:param name="name1" value="value1" />
 <c:param name="name2" value="value2" />
 <c:param name="name3" value="value3" />
</c:import>
```

Within the child.jsp you can read the parameters by using:

```
 <c:out value="${param.name1}" />
 <c:out value="${param.name2}" />
 <c:out value="${param.name3}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A `TypedProperty` is nothing but a Wrapper to `HashMap`. So that's nothing to do here with passing values from one JSP to another JSP. Without invoking a command, you can't pass a Java object to another JSP.
And that is the very basic of Command Framework. I would prefer to go with the first answer.